# How can I get the Facebook user name from sharekit?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, ios5

I am creating an app that contain sharekit, That works fine. But now I want to retrieve the id,username ,gender,firstname,lastname,email, for showing user profile in my app.

But I am not able to retrieve these..

i write this code

```
SHKFacebook *facebook = [[SHKFacebook alloc] init];
    [facebook getAuthValueForKey:@"username"];
```

any ideas??

thanx!!

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience with sharekit, it is only a way to post information not retrieve information. I recommend using ASIHTTPRequest - check out the following example:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1488/how-to-use-facebooks-new-graph-api-from-your-iphone-app

-Jeanine